# My navbar won't align with the center of the page?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

My navbar won't align with the center of the page. In fact any code i added to change the margins between each individual link is also not working, idk why that is. I made the position absolute because I couldn't find any other way to get the navbar to go in front of the background/ the slideshow in my side (not shown here). I have included a fiddle. Also I tried making a centered navbar that would be transparent, have my next element be behind it but I couldn't.

https://jsfiddle.net/ep93zz08/

HTML:

```
   <div id="navbar" class="li flex-container nav row">
            <a class="nav-link flex-item " href="index.html">PHOTOGRAPHER</a>
            <a class="nav-link flex-item" href="#">PORTFOLIO</a>
            <a class="hplogo-a flex-item " href="idex.html"><img id="logo" src="http://www.dynamicaudiovideo.com/_Media/samsung_logo_large.jpeg" alt=""></a>
            <a class="nav-link flex-item" href="Investment.html">INVESTMENT + FAQ</a>
            <a class="nav-link flex-item" href="#">BLOG</a>
        </div>
```

CSS:`

```
body{
    margin:0;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    font-family: Calibri;
    font-style: normal;
    font-variant: normal;
  background:black;

}

.nav{
    position: absolute;
    list-style-type: none;
    display: inline;
    z-index: 2;
    text-align: center;

}

.resize-anchor{
    display: inline-block;
    height: auto;
    width: 300px;
}
.hplogo-a{
    display: inline-block;
    height: auto;
    width: 200px;
    min-width: 200px;
}

a:hover{
    color:#D1946F;
    text-decoration: none;
}

a:link{
    color:#D1946F;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.navlink, .hplogo-a{
    text-align: center;
    display:inline-block;
    margin-left: 50px;
    margin-right: 50px;
    padding:0;
}
.nav-link{
    color:white;
    text-decoration: none;
    white-space: nowrap;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: Calibri;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-style: normal;
    font-variant: normal;
    line-height: 26.4px;
    margin-top: 20px;
}

.sticky {

    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%
    z-index: 3;
}
.li{
    text-align: center;

}

.flex-container {
    display: flex;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    -webkit-align-items: center;
    align-items: center;
}

.flex-item {
    margin: 5px;
}

img{
    width: 100%;
}
`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be better to add CSS rules for `#navbar` selector. Because rules for `.nav` will affect to all HTML elements with `.nav` class. Using the `#navbar` selector, the rules will only affect the specific div with that id. Try to remove the rules for `.nav` and add this:

```
#navbar {
    position: relative;
    list-style-type: none;
    z-index: 2;
    justify-content: center;
}
```

to adjust the margins between links:

```
#navbar a {
  margin-right: 20px;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ep93zz08/8/

Comment: Is that true for all classes vs id's? Do all css rules applied to a parent class also apply to it's children, but not for id's?

Comment: If you set rules for #navbar * selector, it will affect to all children elements. #navbar, #navbar * will affect #navbar and all it's children elements.
The same for the classes selectors. But I mentioned about using the id instead of class, because there should be only one element with a given ID in a document and there can be a lot of elements with class attribute.

Answer (score 0):

One easy way that I used when trying to center the navbar is under .li or ul.li use the following:

```
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
```

Or you can use the following and add your own flare to it:

```
 #nav {
       width:750px;
       margin:0 auto;
       list-style:none;
}
#nav li {
       float:left;
}
#nav a {
       display:block;
       text-align:center;
       width:150px; /* fixed width */
       text-decoration:none; 
}
```

With the following html to follow up:

```
<ul id="nav">
  <li><a href="#">HOME</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">CAPABILITIES</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">ABOUT US</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">RFQ</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">CONTACT US</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add this styling to the navbar ID.

```
  left:50%; transform:translateX(-50%);
```

You should look at some of your CSS because you are using position absolute on the navbar ID and then display flex on the flex-container class of that same div. It looks like you are trying to center the div using two different methods.

Comment: This worked but I still can't seem to adjust the margin between the elements within the nav?

Comment: @BrownBoii333 I took your original code and modified it to eliminate some of the duplicate styling and clean it up. This solution uses just flexbox without the position absolute to achieve the centered nav and then padding to increase or decrease the space between links.

http://jsfiddle.net/9x2gjeka/